# Find the limit of multivariable function or prove it doesn't exist.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be
$$f(x,y) = \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}+\frac{1}{x}\right)}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}+\frac{1}{y}\right)}$$
Say if
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0^+,0^+)} f(x,y)$$
exists. If it does, evaluate it.

I tried to multiply by the conjungate $\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}+\frac{1}{x}\right)}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{x^4+y^4}+\frac{1}{y}\right)}$, but it still seems messy. I don't know tow to approach this task.

Comment: when $y \ll x \ll 1$, $$f(x,y) \approx \frac 1{x^2}  - \infty$$ but when $x \ll y \ll 1$, $$f(x,y) \approx \infty - \frac 1{y^2}$$

Comment: Is it really that helpful or even correct? You will just get $\infty-\infty$

Comment: Yes, it is correct and quite helpful, if you understand what it is telling you. If a double limit exists, then single limits, taken on any path to the point, will all exist and all have the same limit. Think about that as you examine my earlier comment again.

Comment: I know that the easiest way is to show a different path, but your comment shows indeterminate form.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am tagging you.

Comment: What my comment is telling you is that paths are available where $f(x,y) \to -\infty$ and where $f(x,y) \to \infty$, For the first, you can choose a path tangent to the $x$ axis ($y \ll x$), for the second, you can choose a path tangent to the $y$ axis ($x \ll y$).

Comment: And I have no clue what "tagging you" even means.